# How to install an application to iPhone without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, deployment, installation, itunes

We want to move an application to iPhone, without iTunes. There are two questions: 1) how does the application which moves other applications to iPhone connect to iPhone? 2) if we use iTunes to do that, which method implement connecting to iPhone in iTunes's API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a public API for communicating with the iPhone. To install an app you will have to use an Apple tool, either iTunes, Xcode, or the iPhone Configuration Utility.

If it is acceptable to use iTunes, you can make an ad hoc build and [package it as an IPA](http://idotcomllc.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/how-to-build-a-ipa-file-from-xcode/) file, to allow people to easily install it through iTunes without going through the App Store.

Comment: +1 though it's probably possible to do it with a jailbroken iphone.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways come to mind:

**1) You can do this with [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/)**

It allows you to upload your app to a website, and manage the process of delivering builds to developers/testers using a web based interface. Note that it uses a feature [detailed here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the Apple docs. Try it.... You won't be disappointed!

Note that you can have 2 types of licenses with Apple for development:

- "Developer" license - costs ~ $100/year. Requires you register each device you want to develop and deploy your application with.
- "Enterprise" license - costs ~ $300/year, and *doesn't* require that you register each device. But you have to be a registered business of some sort for this.

So if you have an Enterprise license with Apple, you can deploy to any device with TestFlight, without needing it to be registered with Apple's dev center (or using iTunes or the following tool as well!)

**2) Use the [iPhone Configuration Utility from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466):**

This is a tool intended for Enterprise use, but it can be used by anyone. It provides a way to install lots of applications on a device very simply, by pretty much clicking a checkbox.  It's available for Mac and Windows. You can get to more info about it on [this page](http://www.apple.com/ca/support/iphone/enterprise/), by searching for "iPhone Configuration Utility"